# reshape de dataframe en R

Tags: r, rstudio, ciencia-de-datos

[image: reshape de dataframe]

Busco llegar al resultado de la tabla 2 ya he intentado con reshape pero no me lo realiza como lo estoy buscando .
alguien puede ayudarme ?
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, es fundamental que añadas el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, sino tu pregunta parece (no digo que lo sea) del tipo "me hacen mi tarea?" también se agradece un [mcve]. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se resuelve usando la función gather del paquete tidyr

```
library(tidyverse)

Tabla1 %>%
  gather(key = tipoc, value = suma_tipoc, -año, -mes)
```